# Missables in Demon's Souls

Tags: demons-souls

Are there any items I should be looking out for before I lose the chance to get it? I've read about how there are no missables on this game because everything is available again at NG+, but what about the first game iteration?

I haven't played much yet, cleared the first boss in world 1 (Boletarian Palace), and I'm playing world 2 (Stonefang Tunnel) now. There's a part of world 2 where there's a fireball throwing enemy behind a bridge that collapses if you try to walk over it. After the bridge collapsed, even after I 'reloaded' the map by going back to the nexus, it is still collapsed. There's an item right beside that enemy that I can never reach because of this.

Comment: Regarding the bridge: It may well be collapsed, but there should be a beam still intact, which you can (carefully) walk across to get the item.

Comment: Yeah, I found out about that beam after reading a walkthrough for that area. I feel like an idiot now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There a few missable items in Demon's Souls.

The first, as pointed out by Jim Bolia, is that worlds have different tendencies, white and black. This determines the difficulty of enemies, souls dropped, et cetera. At Pure White World or Pure Black world tendency, however, the maps themselves sometimes change. New paths may open up, or an additional (unique) enemy may spawn.  World Tendency is effected by a variety of factors, such as beating a boss, dying, defeating certain enemies, et cetera.

See below for more details on what you find at each, and how the system works.
Effects of:

> White World Tendency
>
> White World Tendency has the following
>   effects.
>
> ```
> Decreases enemy HP, attack and defence power
> Enemies drop fewer upgrade stones
> Enemies drop more healing items.
> Attack power is increased in Soul Form. Increases 10% at White, and 20% at Pure White.
> ```
>
> See the list of White World Tendency
>   Events. Black World Tendency
>
> Black World Tendency has the following
>   effects.
>
> ```
> Increases enemy HP, attack and defence power
> Enemies hold more Souls
> Enemies are more likely to drop rare items
> The Black Phantoms versions of enemies and NPCs appear in specific locations 
> Black Phantom versions of normal monsters have a 100% drop rate
> for their primary items.
> Primeval Demons appear in specific locations in each world. Note that
> Primeval Demons will appear slightly
> before a world is Pure Black, so this
> is not a good way to judge if you have
> achieved Pure Black World Tendency.
> This demon will still be there when
>  the world is Pure Black.
> Your character's maximum HP in Soul Form is reduced.
> ```
>
> See the list of Black World Tendency
>   Events.

Changing it:

> Changing World Tendency
>
> Nomenclature
>
> Each action below is followed by a
>   positive or negative number.
>
> ```
> Positive numbers shift the World Tendency towards White (e.g. +1 means
> ```
>
> one step towards Pure White World
>   Tendency)
>       Negative numbers shift the World Tendency towards Black (e.g. -1 means
>   one step towards Pure Black World
>   Tendency)
>
> Towards White
>
> ```
> Kill a Demon (boss) in a particular World (+1)  
> Kill the Red Dragon (+1) in 1-2  
> Kill the Blue Dragon (+1) in 1-4  
> Kill the Black Phantom Form of one of the 5 special named NPCs that
> appear in Pure Black World Tendency  
>     Defeat Black Phantom Executioner Miralda (+3) in 1-1  
>     Defeat Black Phantom Scirvir, the Wanderer (+3) in 2-2  
>     Defeat Black Phantom Lord Rydell (+3) in 3-1  
>     Defeat Black Phantom Satsuki (+3) in 4-1  
>     Defeat Black Phantom Selen Vinland (+3) in 5-2  
> Defeat a Primeval Demon (+3) (once per world per game)  
> Defeat Black Phantom NPC (see above) and 1 Primeval Demon without  
> returning to Nexus. (+6) (once per
> game)
> Defeat Black Phantom NPC (see above) and Primeval Demon without
> returning to Nexus, and then defeat 1
> Boss. (+7) (once per game)  
> Kill an invading Black Phantom  
> Ressurect a summoned Blue Phantom
> ```
>
> Note: To maintain White Tendency after
>   defeating a boss (approx 45% shift to
>   White), then go to the Nexus and
>   commit suicide in the Nexus. Death in
>   body form in a world equates to a
>   (30%) shift back to black tendency,
>   undoing all the effect of killing the
>   boss. Towards Black
>
> ```
> Die outside the Nexus while in Body form (-1)
> Kill Old King Doran (-2) in 1-1
> Kill the Body Form of one of the 5 special named NPCs that appear in Pure
> White World Tendency
>     Kill Body Form Executioner Miralda (-3) in 1-1
>     Kill Body Form Scirvir, the Wanderer (-3) in 2-2
>     Kill Blue Phantom Lord Rydell (-3) in 3-1
>     Kill Body Form Satsuki (-3) in 4-1
>     Kill Body Form Selen Vinland (-3) in 5-2
>
>  Suicide in the Nexus in Body Form (+0) This affects World Tendency in
>  the Nexus, but there are no World
>  Tendency events there.
>  Suicide in the Nexus in Soul Form (+0)
>  Die in any world in Soul Form (+0)
>  Kill the Vanguard (+0) in 4-1
> ```

Source: http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/world-tendency

Next, there are also the [Mephistopheles Quests](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/mephistopheles) and [Yurt, The Silent Chief.](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/yurt) The Mephistopheles  Quests appear if you kill Yurt, and have [Black Character tendency.](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/character-tendency) She will offer you assassination quests to kill many of the NPCs in the Nexus, and rewards you for doing so. Of them, the only unique item is the [Foe's Ring.](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/foe-s-ring) It should be noted that the NPCs will **not** respawn if you kill them. So doing so is not a good idea before the final boss.

Yurt is related to the above, but slightly differnt. You find him locked up in 3-2, and upon freeing him he will begin killing NPCs (the ones that Mephistopheles wanted you to kill, as well as a few more).To unlock him you need to take an alternate path through 3-2, so it is very possible to miss him. Killing him will grant you the Gloom Set.

There is also the [Demonbrandt](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/demonbrandt) obtained by fighting [Old King Doran](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/walk1-1-oldking). He is located in World 1-1, and you need the Demonbrandt to later obtain the [Northen Regelia](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/northern-regalia).

On a final note, the game doesn't force any items on you, and so it's possible to miss more then this on your way through, but for most items you can normally still get them if you just revisit the level.

Answer (score 0):

There are some events that only trigger when a world is in a certain white/black tendency. In order to do/get "everything," sometimes you'll have to manipulate the world from pure-white to pure-black for example. See http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/world-tendency